# To talk about a hobby, should I say "I like swimming" or "I like go swimming"?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like) gives this example

> I don't **like** upsetting people

with this formula [ + -ing verb ], based on which, I could say "I like swimming", although I've also seen "I like go swimming". It seems that both forms could be used to talk about a hobby, when should I use which one?

Answer (score 1):

"I like go swimming" doesn't work. 
It IS okay to say, "I like **to** go swimming," and it means pretty much the same thing as, "I like swimming."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which one you would use in actual everyday situation, such as meeting a new friend? If neither, what would you say?

Comment: I don't know why Paul's answer has been downvoted. _Swimming_ is the action itself, _going swimming_ is the whole business of taking your swimming kit to a pool or beach and spending time in the water. You can use either to tell someone what your hobby is.

Answer (score 0):

Some people would say "I like swimming" and "I like **to go** swimming" mean the same - but they don't necessarily.

Lots of people say they like football - which more often than not means they enjoy *watching* football, not playing it.

Swimming is not as well known as a spectator sport, but still "I like *to go* swimming" makes it clear that you actively take part.